# count the number of nodes in a specific level in treeview

Tags: ms-access, treeview, vba

I'm using the treeview control and am trying to count the number of nodes in a specific level. For instance lets say I have a tree view like this

```
Lvl1  Lvl2    Lvl3
------------------------
Node1
     -n1c1
          -another child
     -n1c2
     -n1c3
          -another child
          -another child

Node2
     -n2c1
          -another child
          -another child
     -n2c2
          -another child
```

So in lvl1, I would get a count of 2 back, in lvl2 a count of 5 and in lvl3 a count of 6

the nodes have a key like this:

```
gmNode.Key = rs.Fields(0).Value & "_" & "0" & "_0"
```

where the second and third position of the key (delimited by _ ) signifies the level its in, and the node position in that level.

I've done something like this:

```
Dim gmNode as Node
Dim node   as TreeNode
Dim count  as Integer

For each node in gmNode.key (asdf_0_0)
      count += 1
Next
```

but that gives me the child count for a specific parent only. I'm looking for the count for an entire level.

Comment: You will need to resort to recursion to solve problems like these, because you don't know off hand how many levels you have.

Comment: Jeanno, I'm fairly new to this, can you help me with the recursion, I guess what it implies first? Sorry if it's dumb question but I'm not really familiar with this :-)

Comment: Please check this link for recursion, I wish I could help you more but I am not very familiar with treenodes. I have a question for you is it possible to find out how many levels you have?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you

```
Function CountChildren(tree As treenode) As Long
    CountChildren = 0
    For i = 1 To tree.Nodes.Count
        CountChildren = CountChildren + tree.Nodes(i).Children
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Hey Jeanno, I think that works if you want to count all the nodes in a tree, but no just the nodes in a specific level, right?

Comment: I thought that what you wanted to do, count the children for all the levels